# discord.py restart the command

Tags: discord, command, discord.py, bots

I am making a discord bot and I tried to make a status command that will make my bot's status start changing, so I thought its working pretty well until I realized that I need it to restart and that I have no idea how to do that, so here is my code without the restart part:

```
@client.command()
async def status(ctx):
    await client.change_presence(activity=discord.Streaming(name='firststatus', url='https://www.twitch.tv/my-channel-name'))
    
    await asyncio.sleep(5)
    
    await client.change_presence(activity=discord.Activity(type=discord.ActivityType.watching, name='Secondstatus'))
```

so I did that but I don't know what to put at the end so it'll restart I guess it will be something like client.command.restart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a simple while loop or the built-in discord.py extension `tasks`

```py
from discord.ext import tasks

@tasks.loop(seconds=5)
async def change_status():
    await client.change_presence(activity=discord.Streaming(name='firststatus', url='https://www.twitch.tv/my-channel-name'))
    await asyncio.sleep(5)
    await client.change_presence(activity=discord.Activity(type=discord.ActivityType.watching, name='Secondstatus'))


@client.command()
async def status(ctx):
    change_status.start()
```

The `change_status` function will loop every 5 seconds and change the presence. You can stop it with `change_status.stop()`

#### Reference:

- [`tasks.loop`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/tasks/index.html#discord.ext.tasks.loop)
- [`Loop.start`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/tasks/index.html#discord.ext.tasks.Loop.start)
- [`Loop.stop`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/tasks/index.html#discord.ext.tasks.Loop.stop)

Comment: You don't want to change the presence to the same all the time, right? It will change first to the `Streaming` presence, wait 5 seconds change it to the `Watching` presence, wait 5 seconds change to the `Streaming` presence... Also you might change the delay to 12 seconds, as the ratelimit for changing presences is 5 requests per 60 seconds

Comment: yes but why await asyncio.sleep(5) then? we already have the seconds=5 ok no never mind I just read the whole thing again  thanks!

Comment: Remember to accept the answer if it helped